# How to sort ArrayList using Comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist, comparator

I have a Class Student that Implements a static method

```
public static Comparator<Student> getCompByName()
```

that returns a new comparator object for Student that compares 2 Students objects 
by the attribute 'name'.

I need to now test this by sorting a students ArrayList by 'name' using my function getCompByName().

Here is my Comparator method in my Student class.

```
public static Comparator<Student> getCompByName()
{   
 Comparator comp = new Comparator<Student>(){
     @Override
     public int compare(Student s1, Student s2)
     {
         return s1.name.compareTo(s2.name);
     }        
 };
 return comp;
}
```

And Main where I need to test

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO code application logic here

    //--------Student Class Test-------------------------------------------
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList();
    Student s1 = new Student("Mike");
    Student s2 = new Student("Hector");
    Student s3 = new Student("Reggie");
    Student s4 = new Student("zark");
    students.add(s1);
    students.add(s2);
    students.add(s3);
    students.add(S4);

    //Use getCompByName() from Student class to sort students
```

Can anyone show me how I would use the getCompByName() in my main to actually sort the ArrayList by name?  Im new to comparators and having a hard time with their usages. The method returns a comparator, so Im not sure how this will be implemented. I know I need to use getCompByName() to sort, im just not sure how to implement it.

Comment: First, choose your favorite sorting algorithm.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I need to use the getCompByName() to sort, not another algoritm

Comment: `Collections.sort(students, getCompByName())`

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a `Comparator` does. On its own it just compares two elements. You have to actually write (or use the ones in the JDK) the sorting algorith,.

Comment: @user3345200 You may want to have a look at the official tutorial on [Object Ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). It is concise and well-written and does a good job at explaining how to implement and use a `Comparator` to sort objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method:

```
Collections.sort(students, Student.getCompByName());
```

Also in your code it would be good to use the `List` interface when declaring the `List`:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList();
```

You could also tighten up the code by using a `Student[]` and passing it to the `ArrayList` constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student[] studentArr = new Student[]{new Student("Mike"),new Student("Hector"), new Student("Reggie"),new Student("zark")};
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>(Arrays.asList(studentArr));
    Collections.sort(students, Student.getCompByName());

    for(Student student:students){
        System.out.println(student.getName());
    }
}
```

Here is a [Gist of the full source](https://gist.github.com/kmb385/9477347).

Comment: That's `Collections.sort(*List*, Comparator)`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

```
Collections.sort(students, getCompByName());
```

Note: might be useful to make your comparator a `private static final` variable.

Note 2: modifies the list *in place*; does not create a new list.