# Mutli raw type in java

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of something. I don't now correctly, but I'm pretty sure, that the `Object` has the `compareTo(Object)`, which returns `int` in any cases. So, if I want to implement a `sort(ArrayList)`, Objects may by strings, or integers.

```
private static void sort(ArrayList<String/Integers, or SomethingElse, not sure now> list)
```

I tried to search something like multi raw type, but I didn't find anything.

How should I do it?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314009/how-to-sort-arraylist-using-comparator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `List` consists of `String` elements, it will be sorted into alphabetical order. If it consists of `Date` elements, it will be sorted into chronological order. It will sort any any object/type that contain [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) (implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html))

Reference: [Collections.sort(list)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)

If you try to sort a list, the elements of which do not implement `Comparable`, `Collections.sort(list)` will throw a `ClassCastException`

Comment: well, i need to do sort by myself, but about Comparable was really useful.