# How would I sort given this code

Tags: java

I also have an ArrayList items. I have classes derived from Media. Given the code below, how would I sort the arraylist by duration? e.g.

```
Collections.sort(myMedia, ?);
```

Here is the class

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public abstract class Media implements Comparable<Media>{

    private int duration;
    private String title;

    private String imageFileName;

    private static String imageFileDirectory = "src/resources/";

    public Media(String name, int seconds) {
        this.title = name;
        this.duration = seconds;
        this.imageFileName = "";
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }    

    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int d) {
        this.duration = d;
    }

    public String getImageFileName() {
        return imageFileName;
    }

    public void setImageFileName(String imageFileName) {
        this.imageFileName = imageFileName;
    }

    public static String getImageFileDirectory() {
        return imageFileDirectory;
    }

    public static void setImageFileDirectory(String imageFileDirectory) {
        Media.imageFileDirectory = imageFileDirectory;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  this.getTitle() 
                + ", Duration: " + this.getDuration() + "s, " +
                "Cost: " + costInPence() + "p";
    }

    public abstract int costInPence();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Media o) {
        return this.getTitle().compareTo(o.getTitle());
    }

    public static class DurationComparator implements Comparator<Media>{
        public int compare(Media m1, Media m2) {
           return m2.getDuration() - m1.getDuration();
        }
    }

    public static class CostComparator implements Comparator<Media>{
        public int compare(Media m1, Media m2) {
           return m2.costInPence() - m1.costInPence();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Collections.sort(myMedia, new DurationComparator());`

Comment: Excellent. It works :)

Comment: You already wrote Comparator!

Comment: If you want to sort by **duration** you should use the `DurationComparator`. If you want to sort by **title** you don't need to specify any comparator as your `Media` objects define this as their **natural order** (by using `Comparable` with `compareTo`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314009/how-to-sort-arraylist-using-comparator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441846/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

The `Collections#sort` method has two variants.

The **first variant** ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)) only accepts a collection that is to be sorted. It will sort the elements of the collection by their **natural order**. Therefore the elements must implement the interface `Comparable` which yields a `compareTo` method. Your `Media` objects already implement this interface with a meaningful natural order, namely sorting by their **titles**:

```
public abstract class Media implements Comparable<Media> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Media o) {
        return this.getTitle().compareTo(o.getTitle());
    }
}
```

The **other variant** ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-)) accepts a collection and a `Comparator` object. It will then sort the elements based on the order defined by the `Comparator`. You can define `Comparator` on various ways, since Java 8 it became pretty compact. But first let us take a look at the `Comparator` you have already defined, it sorts by **duration**:

```
public static class DurationComparator implements Comparator<Media> {
    public int compare(Media m1, Media m2) {
       return m2.getDuration() - m1.getDuration();
    }
}
```

So if you want to sort by **titles** you should use the first variant. If you want to sort by **duration** you need to create a new instance of `DurationComparator` and use the second variant, alternatively use the compact Java 8 statements. The same holds for your `CostComparator`:

```
// Sort by title
Collections.sort(myMedia);

// Sort by duration
Collections.sort(myMedia, new DurationComparator<>());

// Sort by duration with Java 8
Collections.sort(myMedia, Comparator.comparingInt(Media::getDuration));

// Sort by cost
Collections.sort(myMedia, new CostComparator<>());

// Sort by cost with Java 8
Collections.sort(myMedia, Comparator.comparingInt(Media::costInPence));
```

The `Comparator#comparing` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)) method creates a `Comparator` object that sorts the given elements based on the given **keys**. The method reference points to a method that yields the keys.

As the methods return `int` you may choose the method `Comparator#comparing` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)) instead, it is slightly faster since `int` doesn't need to be boxed into `Integer` then.

Note that since **Java 8** `List`s itself provide a `sort` method too ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-)). So you don't need to call `Collections` anymore:

```
myMedia.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Media::getDuration));
```

Also note that `Comparator` now provides some useful methods ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-)), for example to first sort by one key and if keys are equal then sort by a second key:

```
myMedia.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Media::getDuration)
    .thenComparing(Media::costInPence));
```

Comment: we can actually make the code much more compact and avoid boxing by doing `myMedia.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Media::costInPence))`, `myMedia.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Media::getDuration))` etc. but it's matter of preference.

Comment: @Aominè Yeah, just saw that the methods return `int` by myself. Thanks for the hint.